# Is there any performance impact of using non-alphanumeric characters in string keys for dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

All my keys are strings, but I'm considering to use non-alphanumeric characters such as `+`, `:`, `_`, etc as part of the key.

Is there any performance (or any other) impact of using them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, python dicts will not see any difference in what characters you use in the key string.

They *are* optimized to deal with strings only versus arbitrary key objects, but if you use *only* string values for keys you won't see any difference between using keys without and with non-alphanumeric characters.

The string-only codepath is an optimization for the most common usecase for python dicts: namespaces and function definitions. This is the default mode for a dict; as soon as you store a non-string key in it, the lookup method is switched and you'll have a teensy-weensy slower dict on your hands. This won't matter much in most Python applications though.

Comment: Excellent use of the technical term "teensy-weensy".